# How to get values from a Map with a list of keys using Java8 streams

Tags: java, java-8

I have a Map "M" and a list "L", now i want get the values from that map "M" using those list of keys available in "L". I want to use java 8 Stream concept can anyone help on this.

I coded to print those values but what i need is to get values into a list

list.stream().forEach(s->{System.out.println(map.get(s));});

Comment: you have to do collect(Collectors.toList()) at the last

Comment: i tried.. it is showing syntax error

Comment: Then show what you tried and what error your got.

Answer (score 8):

`map` each element of the `List` to the corresponding value in the `Map` and collect to a `List`:

```
List<String> values =
    list.stream()
        .map(map::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You might want to consider eliminating `null` values (which result from keys not present in the `Map`).